# Possible to use a let within an if/cond?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

I often find myself wanting to work with the current-element in a list and not always have to run a procedure on it to get it, for example to use `elem` rather than `(car sequence)` every time I want to refer to the current element in a sequence. This works...except if the sequence is null, and so I cannot put the `let` before the `null` check. Here is the 'pattern' I was trying to do:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  ; return a list of only those items where the filter predicate returns true
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        ; now that we know we have an active sequence, I want to short-hand 'elem' and 'rest'
        (let (elem car sequence) 
              (rest cdr sequence))
          (display elem)))
```

But then I get an error saying `let: bad syntax`. Is there a way to do the above pattern somehow?

**Upate**: maybe the best way is just to throw a `let` at the top with a simple `if` check? Something like:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  (let ((elem (if (null? sequence) nil (car sequence)))
       (rest (cdr sequence)))
    (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
          (display elem))))
```

Comment: Your approach is correct but your parentheses are off for the let binding

Comment: @coredump does the answer below look ok?

Comment: You should also see [Pattern Matching](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is an addendum to coredump's answer (which is the right one I think) which I started writing last night so I'll leave it for posterity.]

Starting with your code:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        (let (elem car sequence) 
              (rest cdr sequence))
          (display elem)))
```

There are at least three problems here: firstly  you have botched the syntax of `cond`, which is (in part)

```
(cond (<test> <expr> ...)
      ...
      (else <expr> ...))
```

So to repair this you need to add an explicit `else` clause:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        (else
         (let (elem car sequence) 
           (rest cdr sequence))
         (display elem))))
```

Now the problem (and the error from this problem was masking the error in `cond` for some reason) is that you've botched the syntax of `let`, which is (again, in part):

```
(let ((<var> <val>) ...) <expr> ...)
```

You've made two separate errors here: you've missed parens around the binding forms, and the expression is not in the body of the `let` at all.  So, fixing those:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        (else
         (let ((elem car sequence)
               (rest cdr sequence))
           (display elem)))))
```

We now get the final errors: no parens around the calls to `car` & `cdr`.   So fixing those:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        (else
         (let ((elem car sequence)
               (rest cdr sequence))
         (display elem))))
```

Well, now that's still not rigt and that's because you've missed parens around the calls to `car` and `cdr`:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        (else
         (let ((elem (car sequence))
               (rest (cdr sequence)))
           (display elem)))))
```

This now works, but it doesn't actually filter the sequence.  To do that it needs to recurse:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        (else
         (let ((elem (car sequence))
               (rest (cdr sequence)))
           (if (null? elem)
               (filter rest)
               (cons elem (filter rest)))))))
```

It would probably be nicer to raise the inner conditional into the `cond`:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        ((null (car sequence)) (filter (cdr sequence)))
        (else (cons (car sequence) (filter (cdr sequence))))))
```

Although now you have the problem of multiple calls to `car` & `cdr` which I think you wanted to avoid.

One nice way of expressing this if you are using full Racket is to use matching, which can combine checking and binding in a nice way:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  (match sequence
    ['() '()]
    [(cons '() tail)
     (filter tail)]
    [(cons head tail)
     (cons head (filter tail))]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first code snippet is malformed with respect to parentheses. Using an `if` instead of a `cond` here, it can be fixed as follows:

```
(define (filter sequence)
  ; return a list of only those items where the 
  ; filter predicate returns true
  (if (null? sequence) 
      'nil
      ; now that we know we have an active sequence, 
      ; I want to short-hand 'elem' and 'rest'
      (let ((elem (car sequence)) 
            (rest (cdr sequence)))
        (display elem)
        (filter rest))))
```

Note also that I call `filter` recursively. You would need to modify this to also accept a predicate parameter and actually filter elements.

Answer (score 0):

One hack-ish way to do this is to put the `let` at the top -- before the conditional and add `if` checks for each of the `let` variables, for example:

```
(define (filter test sequence)
  (let ((elem (if (null? sequence) nil (car sequence)))
        (rest (if (null? sequence) nil (cdr sequence))))
    (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
          ((test elem) (cons elem (filter test rest)))
          (else (filter test rest)))))
```

```
(filter (lambda (x) (> x 2)) '(1 2 3 4 5))
; (3 4 5)
```